# C++ - Ambiguous Overloaded Template Resolution/Deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, type-deduction

Running the following code snippet, I do not receive any errors and I get my expected result. However, since the second template instantiation is ambiguous ([both type specifiers are references](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/ch01.html)), I am worried that this might not be defined behavior.
**Is this behavior (that the compiler instantiates the most specific overloaded template) guaranteed?**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void Print(const T& x)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void Print(const std::vector<T>& x)
{
    for(auto it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    Print(5); // 5
    Print(v); // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure where to look so a good reference is also greatly appreciated.

Comment: The deduction rules are not easy to follow and make sense of but your code behaves like it should. There is nothing to worry.

Comment: [The page on overload resolution at cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) `partial ordering selects ... as more specialized` and `Informally "A is more specialized than B" means "A accepts fewer types than B".`

Comment: Thanks guys. @super that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const std::vector<T>& x` is a more specialized type than `const T& x`. A more specialized type is considered a better match for overload resolution. Hence, your code behaves like it should.

Comment: Thanks! I just added the language lawyer tag. Do you know if this behaviour is guaranteed according to the deduction rules?

Comment: @pooya13, yes, it is.